# Regex: Not capture after a specific character if it exists

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex expression to not capture after a specific characters if they exist in the string:

> david.com/destination_in=Los+Angeles&1234
>
> david.com/destination_in=Los+Angeles
>
> david.com/destination_in=Los+Angeles#1234

I only want to return Los+Angeles in all cases above

I've been trying with things like `.*david.com/destination_in=(.*)(?:&*|#*)`

But can't get the desire results for all the cases (with or without & and # after the city).

Comment: It's always good to lay down allowed patterns and patterns to be rejected.

Comment: Where are you using this regex? A `.` without a quantifier is a single character, `*` is 0 or more characters `+` is one or more.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/mW5gN0/2) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=destination_in=)[a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+
```

this regex should only select "Los+Angeles" in your example and is flexible in what it matches against